# Python - How to Count How Many Month of a List of Date Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

i'm new to Python and working on my exercise. i have list of two columns, first column contains date value and second column contains numeric values. so i need to calculate how many months from the first column and sort the first column from oldest to newest date based on the date value.

this is what i have so far:

```
import os

import csv

source_csv = os.path.join("..","C:/Users/Desktop/","data.csv")

with open(source_csv,newline="") as csvfile:

    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=",")
    next(csvreader)  # skip the headers

    sortedlist = sorted(csvreader, key=lambda row: row[0], reverse = True)
    print(sortedlist)
```

[image: my list:]

Comment: You can convert the string to month with [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#datetime.datetime.strptime), e.g. `datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%y').month`

Comment: Show us what you've tried. There are tons of duplicates on SO, please search them and try to solve your problem and post your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pandas and datetime packages the operations is straightforward

```
import pandas as pd
#Read the data
df=pd.read_csv('tempdata.csv')

#Convert to a  Date format here
df['NewDate']=df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%y'))

#Extract Month and store as new column
df['Month']=df['NewDate'].apply(lambda x: x.month)

#Sort the data frame in descending dates
df.sort_values('NewDate')
```

[image]